# How can I store the value of a cell upon deleting a row from an HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following table and JavaScript code:

```js
function deleteRow() {
    var td = event.target.parentNode;
    var tr = td.parentNode; // the row to be removed
    tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
    deletedIds.push(tr.cell(0).innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <body>
      <TABLE id="eventTable" border="1" style="border: 1px solid #000000; border-collapse: collapse;" cellpadding="4">
        <TR>
          <TH>ID</TH>
          <TH>Timestamp</TH>
          <TH>Filename</TH>
          <TH>Frequency</TH>
          <TH>Hostname</TH>
          <TH>Port</TH>
          <TH>Band</TH>
          <TH>Start Time</TH>
          <TH>End Time</TH>
          <TH>Delete</TH>
        </TR>
        <TR>
          <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
          <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
          <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
          <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
          <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
          <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
          <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
          <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
          <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
          <TD contenteditable="true">
            <button type='button' value='delete' 'class='center2 ' onclick=‘deleteRow();’> Delete Event </button></TD>
        </TR>
      </TABLE>
```

Upon clicking the `Delete Event` button, I want to store whatever is in the id column of that row in an array.

The `deleteRow` function correctly deletes the row from the HTML table, but yields an error because `tr.cell` is not a valid function.  **How can I store whatever is in the ID column of the deleted row inside the deletedIds array?**

Comment: Given the source in your question, it is impossible for the `deleteRow()` function to do anything.  Nothing executes the function.

Comment: Oh, my b I posted an older version of my delete code, I fixed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is mostly correct just a few errors:

1. You are deleting the element before reading its innerHTML.
2. `tr.cells[i]` is the correct way to access ith column.

Check out the following working snippet.

```js
var deletedIds = [];
function deleteRow() {
    var td = event.target.parentNode;
    var tr = td.parentNode; // the row to be removed
    //deletedIds is the name of the array
    deletedIds.push(tr.cells[0].innerHTML);
    tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
    console.log(deletedIds);
}
```

```html
  <TABLE id="eventTable" border="1" style="border: 1px solid #000000; border-collapse: collapse;" cellpadding="4">
    <TR>
      <TH>ID</TH>
      <TH>Timestamp</TH>
      <TH>Filename</TH>
      <TH>Frequency</TH>
      <TH>Hostname</TH>
      <TH>Port</TH>
      <TH>Band</TH>
      <TH>Start Time</TH>
      <TH>End Time</TH>
      <TH>Delete</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true">
        <button type="button" id="delete0"  onclick="deleteRow()"> Delete Event </button></TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
```

Comment: Create working snippets rather than linking to a fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.
1. Call the function and send element (`button`) to it.
2. Get `tr` and its `cells` collection.
3. Push to array before deleting.

```js
var deletedIds = [];

function deleteRow(el) {
  //var td = event.target.parentNode;
  var tr = el.parentNode.parentNode; // the row to be removed
  deletedIds.push({
    id: el.id,
    td0: tr.cells[0].innerHTML
  });
  tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
  console.log(deletedIds);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <TABLE id="eventTable" border="1" style="border: 1px solid #000000; border-collapse: collapse;" cellpadding="4">
    <TR>
      <TH>ID</TH>
      <TH>Timestamp</TH>
      <TH>Filename</TH>
      <TH>Frequency</TH>
      <TH>Hostname</TH>
      <TH>Port</TH>
      <TH>Band</TH>
      <TH>Start Time</TH>
      <TH>End Time</TH>
      <TH>Delete</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true">
        <button type='button' id='delete0' class='center2' onclick="deleteRow(this);"> Delete Event </button></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
      <TD contenteditable="true">
        <button type='button' id='delete1' class='center2' onclick="deleteRow(this);"> Delete Event </button></TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it differently and apply the id to the row - then store that on the  deletion ie: - tr.attr('id')

```js
var deletedIds = [];

function deleteRow(index) {
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll('#eventTable tr');
    
    rows.forEach(function(row){
       let id = row.getAttribute('id');
       if (id == index) {
        deletedIds.push(id);
        row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
       }
     })
    console.log(deletedIds);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <body>
      <TABLE id="eventTable" border="1" style="border: 1px solid #000000; border-collapse: collapse;" cellpadding="4">
        <TR>
          <TH>ID</TH>
          <TH>Timestamp</TH>
          <TH>Filename</TH>
          <TH>Frequency</TH>
          <TH>Hostname</TH>
          <TH>Port</TH>
          <TH>Band</TH>
          <TH>Start Time</TH>
          <TH>End Time</TH>
          <TH>Delete</TH>
        </TR>
        <TR id="1">
          <TD contenteditable="true">1</TD>
          <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
          <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
          <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
          <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
          <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
          <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
          <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
          <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
          <TD contenteditable="true">
            <button type='button' class='center2 ' onclick="deleteRow(1)"> Delete Event</button>
           </TD>
        </TR>
        <TR id="2">
          <TD contenteditable="true">2</TD>
          <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
          <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
          <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
          <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
          <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
          <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
          <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
          <TD contenteditable="true"></TD>
          <TD contenteditable="true">
            <button type='button' class='center2 ' onclick="deleteRow(2)"> Delete Event</button>
           </TD>
        </TR>
      </TABLE>
```